# Why <!--#include file="top.shtml"--> does not work?

Tags: html, include

I don't understand why the  command does not work in the case below.

The files listed in the code are all in the same directory as the file containing the .html code, but the files I want to include will not load (at least not when I open the file in Chrome).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<link href="helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="dropdown.vertical.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <body>
<!--#include file="top.shtml"-->
<!--#include file="sidemenu.shtml"-->           
      <h1>   Name </h1>  

      <h2>Title </h2>

</body> 
</html>
```

I read that the files that I want to load should be changed to .shtml files which I did, but it did not seem to work. Something of a novice here so I might just not be understanding something. One question is, if it is working, should I see it working if I open the file in Google Chrome, or does it actually have to be on a server as a web page for the code to work?

Comment: It has to be running on a server configured to parse .shtml pages. Opening directly via a browser won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Server-side scripting languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)* like `SSI` -- which you used in your code -- and `PHP` and `ASP` and many more are all executed on the **server**. "Chrome" is just a web browser, and doesn't carry out the server side instructions.

Here is how it works:

- You send the request for a resource to the server (as in your case, the request for the `SHTML` file can be through entering the URI in the address bar of your browser),
- The server gets the request and goes through some processes like carrying out the specified instructions (as in your case, executing the `#include` directives),
- And finally, the server returns the response (in your case as a `HTML` file) back to the client -- i.e. the web browser -- to be presented.